# Making two seaborn countplots that share the same axis

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, frequency-distribution

I'm looking to use seaborn countplots to display the frequency distribution of two different lists of data on one axis. The problem I'm having is that both lists contain unique elements, so I can't simply plot one list using the axis of the larger one.

I've tried using python's count objects, but the axis of the graph didn't match up with the counts displayed on the graph since python dictionaries are unordered.

```
import seaborn as sns


first_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b","n"]
second_list = ["a","b","c","d", "e", "e","d","c","e","q"]


sns.countplot(first_list, color="blue", alpha=.5)
sns.countplot(second_list, color="red",alpha=.5)


plt.show()
```

The code above should display a graph including the frequencies for the unique values "n", and "q", but displays a graph that's axis only includes the values from the second list.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any straightforward way to use seaborn countplots the way you want to without first creating a dataframe. Here is a solution built with numpy and matplotlib based on [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html). I leave it up to you to check if this is more efficient than using a dataframe and countplots.

```
import numpy as np                # v 1.19.2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   # v 3.3.2

first_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "n"]
second_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "e", "d", "c", "e", "q"]

# Create dictionaries from lists with this format: 'letter':count
dict1 = dict(zip(*np.unique(first_list, return_counts=True)))
dict2 = dict(zip(*np.unique(second_list, return_counts=True)))

# Add missing letters with count=0 to each dictionary so that keys in
# each dictionary are identical
only_in_set1 = set(dict1)-set(dict2)
only_in_set2 = set(dict2)-set(dict1)
dict1.update(dict(zip(only_in_set2, [0]*len(only_in_set2))))
dict2.update(dict(zip(only_in_set1, [0]*len(only_in_set1))))

# Sort dictionaries alphabetically
dict1 = dict(sorted(dict1.items()))
dict2 = dict(sorted(dict2.items()))

# Create grouped bar chart
xticks = np.arange(len(dict1))
bar_width = 0.3
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 5))
ax.bar(xticks-bar_width/2, dict1.values(), bar_width,
       color='blue', alpha=0.5, label='first_list')
ax.bar(xticks+bar_width/2, dict2.values(), bar_width,
       color='red', alpha=0.5, label='second_list')

# Set annotations, x-axis ticks and tick labels
ax.set_ylabel('Counts')
ax.set_title('Letter counts grouped by list')
ax.set_xticks(xticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(dict1.keys())
ax.legend(frameon=False)
plt.show()
```

[image: grouped_bar_letter_count]

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to combine your data into one dataframe that you pass to seaborn instead of making two plots on top of each other. I called sns.barplot on the counts instead of using sns.countplot on the original raw values.

```
#convert the lists to series and get the counts
first_list = pd.Series(
    ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b","n"]
).value_counts()

second_list = pd.Series(
    ["a","b","c","d", "e", "e","d","c","e","q"]
).value_counts()

#get the counts as a dataframe
df=pd.concat([first_list,second_list],axis=1)
df.columns=['first','second']

# melt the data frame so it has a "tidy" data format
df=df.reset_index().melt(id_vars=['index'])
```

```
df

   index variable  value
0      a    first    3.0
1      b    first    3.0
2      c    first    2.0
3      d    first    1.0
4      e    first    1.0
5      n    first    1.0
6      q    first    NaN
7      a   second    1.0
8      b   second    1.0
9      c   second    2.0
10     d   second    2.0
11     e   second    3.0
12     n   second    NaN
13     q   second    1.0
```

```
#plot a bar graph and assign variable to hue
sns.barplot(
    x='index',
    y='value',
    hue='variable',
    data=df,
    palette=['blue','red'],
    alpha=.5,
    dodge=False,
)

plt.show()
```

[image: The final plot]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I was curious if there was a way to do this while avoiding creating a dataframe. I'm hoping to graph a relatively large dataset and there seems to be some overhead with the dataframe that I was hoping to avoid.